# How to use \StrBefore in \chapter with optional argument

Tags: table-of-contents, xstring

I want to trim the chapter titles in toc up to first dot.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\chap}[1]{%
    \chapter[\StrBefore{#1}{.}]{#1}
}
\begin{document}
\chap{Some title. Very long}

Foo Bar

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work - what am I missing here? (Xe)LaTeX gives me:

```
Chapter 1.
! Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                               #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.8 \chap{Some title. Very long}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The optional argument to `\chapter` should not contain unprotected assignments.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\chap}[1]{%
    \chapter[\protect\StrBefore{#1}{.}]{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\chap{Some title. Very long}

Foo Bar

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, and preferably in my opinion,

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\chap}[1]{%
    \StrBefore{#1}{.}[\chapterstart]%
    \expandafter\chapter\expandafter[\chapterstart]{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chap{Some title. Very long}

Foo Bar

\end{document}
```

Perhaps the two `\expandafter` commands are not necessary, but this ensures we never rely on a particular value of `\chapterstart`. With this we don't clutter the auxiliary files with `\StrBefore`.